# Silverlight OpenFileDialog causes browser crash

Tags: c#, silverlight, internet-explorer

We have a Silverlight application that allows users to upload documents that are saved in our database.  Recently when clicking the button to choose the file, the OpenFileDialog has caused their browser to crash.  I have replicated this in IE 8/9.  Sometimes with some luck it will work as intended and return the selected file info to the application code, but other times while using the dialog, the cpu core the IE instance is running on will jump to 90%+.  When the dialog is closed IE9 hangs completely while IE8 will pretend to work, letting the UI respond to mouse hovers, but will not take any actual input.

Has anyone else had this problem before?  It seems to be Silverlight/Windows related... there isn't anything wacky about our application code that would cause something like this.  Besides, the crash occurs inside the OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() method.  Not an easy thing to debug.

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Browse" Height="{StaticResource ButtonHeightDouble}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
     x:Name="Browse" Width="{StaticResource ButtonStandardWidthDouble}"  
     Style="{StaticResource GrayButtonStyle}"  
     Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
     Margin="{StaticResource SmallGapVerticallyStackedThickness}"/>
```

C#:

```
public void Browse()
{
    OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog
    {
        Filter = "Quote Files (*.pdf;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.docx;*.doc;*.xlsx;*.xls;*.tif;*.tiff)|*.pdf;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.docx;*.doc;*.xlsx;*.xls;*.tif;*.tiff",
        Multiselect = false
    };

    // wrapping this in a try/catch does not catch anything if it crashes
    if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        try
        {
            // do things with the file;
            // if crash occurs, this code is never reached
            // even if "Open" is clicked in the dialog box
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            SilverlightMessageBoxLibrary.Message.ErrorMessageLarge(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the latest Silverlight installed? Do you have all IE updates installed? Does the problem go away if the page running the Silverlight app is run in the Trusted Sites zone (outside of Protected Mode)?

Comment: We have Silverlight 5.1.20913.0 installed which I believe is the most recent version, and all IE updates are installed.  The app runs at a subdomain and our s.o.p. is to have *.ourdomain.com listed in Trusted Sites with security set to Low; the problem does occur with these settings.